# How to define a recursive notation with overlapping production?

Tags: coq

I am working with labelled transition systems and I want to conveniently express sequences of transitions. I defined the transition type as `Inductive Trans : Label -> State -> State -> Prop` and I would like to encode it as `S1 -{ a }-> S2`. This is trivial so far:

```
Notation "S1 -{ a }-> S2" := (Trans a S1 S2) (at level 70).
```

However, it is common to chain such arrows, and this is where my struggle is. I want to be able to write something like

```
S1 -{ a1 }-> S2 -{ a2 }-> S3 -{ a3 }-> S4 -{ a4 }-> S5
```

which would mean

```
S1 -{ a1 }-> S2 /\ S2 -{ a2 }-> S3 /\ S3 -{ a3 }-> S4 /\ S4 -{ a4 }-> S5
```

All my attempts were futile, some of them really ugly and hacky (eg. an abominable continuation-passing fold). I hope it is fine that I don't attach them. To me, the main recurring problems are that either

- The delimiter (`-{ a }->`) consists of several symbols including an identifier
- Yielded entries share syntactic elements (the middle states)

How to touch it? Is it even possible in Coq? I can go for some syntactic compromises if that's necessary.